# Correr un ejecutable de python en una applicacion angular

Tags: python, angular

Tengo un ejecutable en python que toma un archivo DXF para sacar una descripcion XML. Lo que tengo que hacer ahora es una applicacion web **con angular** que pueda tomar un archivo del usuario y corra dicho ejecutable **en el servidor**. Como puedo llamar a un ejecutable desde angular?

Comment: Hi there, this is [es.so]. Please translate yout question to spanish. Otherwise it will be closed. Bienvenido a [es.so], por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tal como está planteada tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y basada en opiniones. Saludos

Comment: No puedes llamar a un ejecutable *desde Angular*. En todo caso, tu aplicación web hecha con Angular (o cualquier otro framework), puede realizar una llamada al servidor desde el que se cargó y el servidor puede lanzar la aplicación escrita en Python cuando reciba la orden.

Comment: En otras palabras debes hacer una peticion AJAX desde Angular a tu servicio tu servicio ejecutara el script que necesitas, y te devolvera los datos